# Correct tuple return type to avoid non-null/undefined operator?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that for a promise returns a tuple of resolved result and caught error:

```js
function resultOf<T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<[null, T] | [any]> {
  return promise
    .then((data: T): [null, T] => [null, data])
    .catch((err: any) => [err])
  ;
}
```

Now when I call the function and check whether the tuple contains an error, I would expect not to require a non-null assertion operator if there's no error:

```js
  // ...
  const [error, result] = await resultOf(foo());
  if(error) {
    // handle error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
  const bar = result.bar; // <- Object is possibly 'undefined'
  const bar = result!.bar; // <- This is what I'd like to avoid
  // ...
```

So here are my two questions:
* Why doesn't this work?
* How do I correct the types such as to avoid having to add a non-null assertion operator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typescript will not follow such 'entangled' variables to see how they could impact one another. You can use the tuple itself and discriminate the tuple union based on the length, and destructure after:

```
function resultOf<T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<[null, T] | [any]> {
  return promise
    .then((data: T): [null, T] => [null, data])
    .catch((err: any) => [err])
  ;
}

async function x() {
  const r = await resultOf(Promise.resolve({ bar: 1 }));
  if (r.length == 1) {
    // handle error
    return Promise.reject(r[0]);
  }
  var [_, result] = r;
  const bar = result.bar; // <- Ok now
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that would indeed work, but it would introduce additional code and would make the code less clear imho - I'm checking whether there's been an error and even though the array length indicates whether or not there was one, that would be more implicit and thus harder to read imho. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

`error` and `result` seem to be independet of each other. And as such typescript can not know that your function will return either one or the other to be no null or not undefined. The type inference for the tuple does not go that deep.

I guess I would write the first if as

```
if (!result) {
  //...
}
```

the after the if `result` will be defined and non null for sure. And `error` will still be of type any in the Promise.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would mean asking the wrong question (I'm rejecting because of an error, not because the result is falsy - even if the outcome is the same). I would then consider sticking with the non-null operator the better solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well of course. Then the non null operator IS the correct solution. Maybe you could also consider creating an dedcated Error type, return a union like Promise<Error | T> and then check for the Error type. Of course everything is more work than the simple non null operator.

Comment: Indeed, that would be a nice idea. Unfortunately, I have to deal with all kinds of external libraries, so I can't control the error type I get everywhere. I guess I could think about creating a resultOf version for internal and external calls.

Comment: I just thought since TS has become very powerful and can figure out lots of dependencies by now there might be a way and I was missing something ;-)